# jquery colorpicker help

Tags: jquery, html

heres my html:

```
<p class="colorp">
<label for="color1">color1</label>
<input name="color1" id="color1" type="text" size="10" value="ff0000" />
<img src="images/icon-color.png" />
</p>

<p class="colorp">
<label for="color2">color2</label>
<input name="color2" id="color2" type="text" size="10" value="ff0000" />
<img src="images/icon-color.png" />
</p>
```

heres my jquery:

```
    $('.colorp img').ColorPicker({
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            $('.colorp img').ColorPickerSetColor($('.colorp input').val());
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('.colorp input').css('border-color', '#'+hex);
            $('.colorp input').val('#'+hex);
        }
    });
```

all i want this to do is work so i can add as many of these color fields i want. i.e. color3, color4, color5...using the same query code.

however when i use this code it changes ALL fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
    $('.colorp img').ColorPicker({
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            $(this).ColorPickerSetColor($(this).parent().find("input").val());
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $(this).parent().find("input").css('border-color', '#'+hex).val('#'+hex);
        }
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately, i was thinking that but it does not work properly and breaks the colorpicker.